Script to rename Excel tab to cell value in multiple tab worksheet
I have a worksheet with MULTIPLE Sheet Tabs, I need the "Sheet 1" name of the tab to equal the text of a certain cell, across ALL Sheet Tabs. Is there a Macro or Script that can do this for me?

What research have you done and what have you tried so far? A couple points: First, welcome to Superuser. Second, this is not a script-writing service. We're very good at helping you fix or improve something you've already begun though. Third, questions asking that we recommend software or other product to solve your problem are explicitly off topic. Please read the HELP section to better understand all this, then do some research and work up some code to do this, and then if you have problems with this, bring THAT question here.
